# How to Hide/unhide 3d objects in vuforia Unity Ground Plane

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am trying to make an app in AR in which I have some 3d objects placed on same plane ground. I want to make those objects visible when the Gui button is clicked of that specific object and hide the others I have used the following code but it's not working. Whenever I touch the screen all the objects becomes visible overlapping each other, when they should not appear if I touch but click the button.

```
public GameObject 3DModel_One;

public GameObject 3DModel_Two;



public void ButtonClicked(){

    3DModel_One.SetActive(true);
    3DModel_Two.SetActive(false);

}
```

Comment: Have you solved?

Answer (score 0):

Are your objects children of your ground plane? Also are you duplicating the stage when clicked. Those two could be your problem. I have implemented it using this code and it is working :

```
 if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        target.SetActive(false);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse1))
        target.SetActive(true);
```

but my target object is not a child of the ground plane and i am not duplicating the stage.